Carte as a service to run transformation remotely
I've followed steps as mentioned in https://pentaho-public.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/EAI/pages/386803558/Carte+as+a+Windows+Service  and able to install the service without any issues.
However when I executeTransformation from postman or web browser with this carte as a service am getting "Can't run transformation : missed plugin" no where which plugin it is missed.
But same API or browser invokes works if I start carte by running carte.bat under PDI for same slave settings.
Am I missing something here?
NOTE: Am using PDI 9.0V
